# Incorrect integer value: '' for column `project-preprod_db`.`catalog_product_entity`.`has_options` at row 1

Tags: magento2, product, save

Running a custom import script, I'm facing this error for **some** products (some others are perfectly being created without this issue).

> - Error occured on B2C product import :
>   The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again.

> #0 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository->getById(1170, false, NULL, false)

Doing further digging into this we managed to discover the real issue was this one once the request arrives to the database.

> ERROR 1366 (22007): Incorrect integer value: '' for column `project-preprod_db`.`catalog_product_entity`.`has_options` at row 1
> ERROR 1366 (22007): Incorrect integer value: '' for column `project-preprod_db`.`catalog_product_entity`.`required_options` at row 1

In the request

> INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `sku`, `has_options`, `required_options`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, '9', 'simple', '4194-EU-SI-NE', '', '',
> '2022-05-13 12:53:09', '2022-05-13 12:53:09');

For some reasons the fields `has_options`, `required_options` are empty. If i fill them and launch the same request, then it will work.

But my issue is that I don't understand why for some products i'm getting this error on my magento import, while for others I don't.

Considering magento already seems to handle this columns, it makes no sense they are empty (false doesn't mean empty) : `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php`

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    $this->setTypeHasOptions(false);
    $this->setTypeHasRequiredOptions(false);
    $this->setHasOptions(false);
    $this->setRequiredOptions(false);
```

This is the code being used to set all the product attribute before saving it to the repository method

```
            $mageProduct = $this->getProductBySku($sku);
            $mageProduct
                ->setSku($sku)
                ->setName($apiProduct['name'])
                ->setTypeId(ProductType::TYPE_SIMPLE)
                ->setAttributeSetId($this->getMageAttributeSetId($apiProduct))
                ->setVisibility(4)
                ->setPrice(0)
                ->setWeight(0)
                ->setStatus(Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
                ->setWebsiteIds($this->allWebsiteIds)
                ->setTaxClassId(($apiProduct['modelType'] == 'Machine' || $apiProduct['modelType'] == 'Product') ? 11 : 10)
                ->setUrlApi($productApiUrl)
                ->setUrlKey($urlKey)
                ->setShortDescription($apiProduct['headline'])
                ->setNespressoDescription($nesDescription)
                ->setCategoryIds(explode(',', $categories))
                ->setRootCat($apiProduct['rootCategory']);




/**
 * @param string $sku
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
 */
protected function getProductBySku($sku)
{
    try {
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
    }
    return $product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try (if you haven't already) setting `has_options` and `required_options` to `0` .  Maybe Mysql interprates the empty value as null and this field is set to notNull.

Comment: First things i tried.  I tried 0 and 1. I tried in my import script and inside the save method from the repository. Nothing change. That being said we are not supposed to set these value anyway they are calculated on the beforeSave automatically...at least they should be.

Comment: Are you trying to update or create products or both?

Comment: For creation are you using Factory ?

Comment: Both but in that specific case i'm just speaking about creation. I'm adding the method used in the question.

Comment: What version of magento are you using, mybe its a bug that been solved in the next versions ? Also try disabling modules which are not included in the plain magento installation, maybe some of theme have a functionality which breaks your import.

Comment: Also compare two lines from your import file , one from a working example and one from non working. Maybe the values of some fields are not correct or empty and the error you are getting is misleading.

Comment: Also somehting that I noticed, you are using the same code for creating the product also the same code for updating. When the product does exist, it is better to update only the fields that usualy can change.  Like type, attributeSet, Urls, tax-class,websiteIds, visibility you shouldnt change them on update because they are usualy not changed.

Comment: It's not consistent, the same product can successfully be imported from a sandbox env and not from an other. But in every case we reach the same error due to these two attributes. i don't think it's a missleading error. This imports run from a cli command, so we can exclude theme.

Comment: Then maybe its the server configuration, try doing the same thing on local enviroment. 
https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento is easy way to setup development enviroment.

Comment: Try creating the product with only the required attributes, to see if it still happens.